# SoapUI + Groovy + Fetch last ID value from response payload

Tags: groovy, soapui

In SoapUI response using Groovy, I am not able to fetch last ID value ie 125114.

```
http://199.xxx.10.20:8080/test_link/masters/125114
```

How can fetch that value?

Comment: What You need to fetch exactly the value '125114' from a String variable?

Comment: Answer is mentioned in below list

Answer (score 2):

You can split the url by '/' and get the last element. A possible groovy code to do this in SOAPUI:

```
def url = ('http://199.xxx.10.20:8080/test_link/masters/125114');
def strArray = url.split("/");
def fetchId = strArray.last();
log.info fetchId;
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks buddy, got the output by replacing split with tokenize.

Comment: Agreed, I also gone through the api site, but always getting error about format.

Comment: Don't worry maybe soapui version or java version where is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use of tokenize, gives the result.

```
def url = ('http://199.xxx.10.20:8080/test_link/masters/125114');
def strArray = url.tokenize('/');
def fetchId = strArray.last();
log.info fetchId;
```